# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation while deploying on wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I am trying to deploy application over wildfly. Its throwing exception on run time.

standalone-full.xml

```
     <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/TDS" pool-name="TDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://test-mysql.com:3306/abc</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>abc</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Comment: Have you tried to google? Look here for instance: https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/ . JBoss/WildFly uses OSGI and so called modules. Define a new module for MySQL JDBC driver. Restart WildFly. Then the class will be found.

Comment: We need more details. What version of WildFly are you using? How did you install the MySQL driver? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: wildfly 10 i am using and connector jar is 5.1.35 version

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace? I could post an answer using jboss cli but I need to be sure that this is your problem.